# Перезапуск firefox на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, imacros

На *Ubuntu* не работает скрипт (на *vps* установлены `xfce4 vnc4server nano cron firefox`).

Скрипт нужен для того, чтобы следить за тем, чтобы *firefox* со скриптом `imacros://run/?
m=fm6_v6.09c.js` был запущен на *vps*.

1. Создайте файл `firefoxtest` в `/bin`:

`touch /bin/firefoxtest`

```
#------------- /bin/firefoxtest---------------

#!/bin/sh

number_of_cs=`ps ax | grep -c firefox`

if [ ${number_of_cs} -lt 2 ]; then

firefox imacros://run/?m=fm6_v6.09c.js & > /dev/null 2>&1

fi

#----------------------------------------------
```

2. `chmod +x /bin/firefoxtest`
3. Добавьте в /etc/crontab строчку Например, тест каждые 5 минут:

`*/5 * * * * root firefoxtest`

Всё делаю, как описано, но *firefox* со скриптом `imacros://run/?m=fm6_v6.09c.js` не запускается.

Comment: Вообще конечно полезней было бы поотлаживать скрипт, если он не работает: посмотреть, запускается ли просто `firefox imacros://run/?m=fm6_v6.09c.js & > /dev/null 2>&1`, что получается в `${number_of_cs}`, как работает `if`...

Answer (score 2):

скрипт написан явно небрежно и (в некоторых местах) просто неверно.
предлагаю такой вариант:

```
#!/bin/sh
# получаем количество запущенных процессов с именем firefox
number_of_cs=$(pgrep firefox | wc -l)
# если это количество меньше одного, то
if [ ${number_of_cs} -lt 1 ]; then
# запускаем программу firefox с параметром, взятым в кавычки
# и перенаправляем stdout и stderr процесса в /dev/null
firefox "imacros://run/?m=fm6_v6.09c.js" &>/dev/null 2>&1
# конец условия
fi
```

Comment: пожалуйста подскажите.что делает этот скрипт. (что он должен выполнить). спасибо.